# Ionic 2.0.0-rc.0 + Firebase 3.4.1-rc.2 + AngularFire2@2.0.0-beta.5 -

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, angularfire2

I am having different issues trying to use Ionic 2, Firebase 3, AngularFire 2 latest versions.

Issues:

```
node_modules/angularfire2/angularfire2.d.ts(13,66): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.

typings/modules/firebase/index.d.ts(498,1): error TS2300: Duplicate
identifier 'export='.

at ReturnStatement.eachChild (/Users/ME/project/node_modules
/rollup/dist/rollup.js:5168:5)                                                 
at ReturnStatement.bind (/Users/ME/project/node_modules/roll
up/dist/rollup.js:5151:7)                                                      
at BlockStatement.bind (/Users/ME/project/node_modules/rollu
p/dist/rollup.js:5617:9)                                                       
at FunctionDeclaration.bind (/Users/ME/project/node_modules/
rollup/dist/rollup.js:6405:13)                                                 
at ExportNamedDeclaration.bind (/Users/ME/project/node_modul
es/rollup/dist/rollup.js:6223:44)
```

**EDIT**:

Ok, after I add this to my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{ "compilerOptions": {
... 
"typeRoots": [
  "../node_modules/@types"
],

// ADD THIS
"types": [
  "firebase"
]
}
}
```

I am having this issue:

```
Error: Module /Users/me/project/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/firebase/firebase-browser.js does not export initializeApp (imported by /Users/me/project/node_modules/angularfire2/angularfire2.js)
at Module.trace (/Users/me/project/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:7677:29)
at ModuleScope.findDeclaration (/Users/me/project/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:7300:22)
at Scope.findDeclaration (/Users/me/project/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:5351:39)
at CallExpression.bind (/Users/me/project/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:5826:28)
at /Users/me/project/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:5151:50
at ReturnStatement.eachChild (/Users/me/project/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:5168:5)
at ReturnStatement.bind (/Users/me/project/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:5151:7)
at BlockStatement.bind (/Users/me/project/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:5617:9)
at FunctionDeclaration.bind (/Users/me/project/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:6405:13)
at ExportNamedDeclaration.bind (/Users/me/project/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:6223:44)
```

**UPDATE**:

I've found this
https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/545#issuecomment-248712121

But its not working perfectly yet.

Error:

```
firebase.js:10Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigator' of undefined
```

Any help, please?

Answer (score 0):

A fellow programmer wrote a solution on his [blog](https://playcode.org/getting-started-with-ionic-2-rc0-firebase-3-angularfire-2/). It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I try to keep my [Ionic 2 + AngularFire 2 config tutorial](https://javebratt.com/ionic2rc0-firebase-angularfire2/) up-to-date.

Short story:

#### Make sure everything is up-to-date

`$ npm install -g ionic@latest cordova typescript`

#### Install the latest version of `@ionic/app-scripts`

`$ npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev`

#### Install Firebase and AngularFire2

`$ npm install @types/request@0.0.30 --save-dev --save-exact
$ npm install firebase angularfire2 --save`

#### Initialize everything in `app.module.ts`

```

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
// Importing pages
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

// Import the AF2 Module
import { AngularFireModule, AuthProviders, AuthMethods } from 'angularfire2';

// AF2 Settings
export const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "",
authDomain: "",
databaseURL: "",
storageBucket: "",
messagingSenderId: ""
};

const myFirebaseAuthConfig = {
provider: AuthProviders.Password,
method: AuthMethods.Password
}

@NgModule({
declarations: [
MyApp,
HomePage
],
imports: [
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig, myFirebaseAuthConfig)
],
bootstrap: [IonicApp],
entryComponents: [
MyApp,
HomePage
],
providers: [
]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

```

Answer (score 0):

To solve `firebase.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigator' of undefined` issue you need to add `useStrict: false`. It should be placed in the right place if you use something like this:

```js
    rollup.rollup({
    })
    .then(function (bundle) {
        bundle.write({
            format: "iife",
            dest: "./dist/app.js",
            useStrict: false
        });
    });
```